# Saving XML file to disk

Tags: c#, xml, file, save, disk

I'm trying to save an `XDocument` object to disk, as an .xml file. The object seems well formed in the debugger, I'm only having an issue saving the actual file. Here is what I'm doing :

```
       //ofx is an `XElement` containing many sub-elements of `XElement` type
        XDocument document = new XDocument(ofx);

        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
        settings.Indent = true;

        //destinationPath is a string containing a path, like this
        // e.g : "C:\\Users\\Myself\\Desktop"  
        using (var stream = File.Create(destionationPath + @"export.xml"))
        {
            List<byte[]> header = new List<byte[]>();

            byte[] newline = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Environment.NewLine);

            List<string> headers = new List<string>();
            headers.Add("foo"); 

            // Just adding some headers here on the top of the file. 
            // I'm pretty sure this is irrelevant for my problem

            foreach (string item in headers)
            {
                header.Add(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(item));
                header.Add(newline);
            }

            header.Add(newline);

            byte[] bytes = header.SelectMany(a => a).ToArray();

            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
            {
                document.Save(writer);
            }

        }
```

Whenever I call this, I have no file in the target directory.

Notes : The directory is well-formed too, as well as the file name. This is  verified in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you're creating the path badly. Following the comment it you have

```
string destionationPath = "C:\\Users\\Myself\\Desktop";
destionationPath + @"export.xml" // evaluates to: "C:\\Users\\Myself\\Desktopexport.xml"
```

You are missing `"\\"` between directory and file name.

The following code works fine for me.

```
namespace TestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Tmp();
        }

        public static void Tmp()
        {

            //ofx is an `XElement` containing many sub-elements of `XElement` type
            XDocument document = new XDocument(new XElement("myName", "myContent"));

            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
            settings.Indent = true;

            //destinationPath is a string containing a path, like this
            // e.g : "C:\\Users\\Myself\\Desktop"  
            string destionationPath = "D:\\Temp\\xml_test\\";
            using (var stream = File.Create(destionationPath + @"export.xml"))
            {
                List<byte[]> header = new List<byte[]>();

                byte[] newline = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Environment.NewLine);

                List<string> headers = new List<string>();
                headers.Add("foo");

                // Just adding some headers here on the top of the file. 
                // I'm pretty sure this is irrelevant for my problem

                foreach (string item in headers)
                {
                    header.Add(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(item));
                    header.Add(newline);
                }

                header.Add(newline);

                byte[] bytes = header.SelectMany(a => a).ToArray();

                stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
                {
                    document.Save(writer);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To avoid such situations *never* create create path by yoursef. Use `Path` class instead:

```
Path.Combine(destionationPath, @"export.xml")
```

Comment: Well that was exactly it ! Thanks man ;) Good answer and good explanation on top